# How to avoid creating many binary switching variables in GEKKO

Tags: python, optimization, prediction, spline, gekko

I am solving for 14 variables by minimizing on the order of thousands of equations with `IMODE = 3` in `GEKKO`.

Each equation is the squared error between the true response and the prediction of a P-spline model (*i.e.*, penalized B-spline):

`eq[i] = m.Minimize((y_true[i] - spline(coeffs, knots, vars)[i]) ** 2)`.

The spline models are constituted of their coefficients and knots (which are previously calculated) along with the 14 variables to optimize.

When building the P-spline models for `GEKKO`, I need to check in-between which knots the value of a variable lies. I tried using both `m.if2` and `m.if3` to achieve this; however, both of these logical functions create many additional binary switching variables, especially for splines with many pieces. In the end, I end up with tens of thousands of binary switching variables. These outnumber the equations, resulting in the number of degrees of freedom being less than 0.

**Question**: How can I avoid using `m.if2` or `m.if3` to build my splines?

**Note**: I am aware that `GEKKO` has the prebuilt object `m.bspline`; however, it appears that it can only do 2D B-splines with two independent variables, while my splines can have over ten independent variables.

Comment: Link to a follow-on question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76477747/using-b-spline-method-of-the-form-z-fx-y-to-fit-z-fx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `m.if2()` function uses MPCCs instead of binary variables. Additional slack variables and equations are created when the `m.if2()` function is used. The `m.if2()` function can be numerically unreliable. The `m.if3()` function is typically more reliable, but it requires the additional binary variables and an MINLP solver (APOPT) to find the solution. `Negative degrees of freedom` is a warning and may still solve because inequality constraints may not be active at the solution.

One additional thing to consider is the `spline(coeffs, knots, vars)[i]` is not re-evaluated during the solution. The Gekko model is compiled into byte-code and there are no call-backs into the original functions. Because the spline is evaluated once during the model initialization, could the position be determined either before or after the solve?

A final suggestion is to use a [machine learned model](https://apmonitor.com/pds/index.php/Main/RegressionOverview) such as a Neural Network, Gaussian Processes, Support Vector Regressor, or similar form that can be imported into Gekko with [ML functions](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ml.html) after it has been trained with sklearn or tensorflow / keras.

Comment: Thank you very much for your final suggestion as it has sparked some ideas. If I understand correctly, a Gekko ML model (that has been trained in sklearn, for example) can make a prediction with Gekko variables as the argument. If so, that would be exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: And when setting up a Gekko ML model, which has minimized equations containing predict method calls, is the model also compiled into byte-code with no original call-backs to the predict methods?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The `sklearn` model is translated into Gekko form before it is compiled.