# Using B-spline method of the form z = f(x, y) to fit z = f(x)

Tags: python, optimization, prediction, spline, gekko

As a potential solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76476327/how-to-avoid-creating-many-binary-switching-variables-in-gekko), how could one coerce [`GEKKO`](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)'s `m.bspline` method which builds 2D B-splines in the form `z = f(x, y)` to build 1D B-splines in the form `z = f(x)`?

More specifically, the 2D method takes in the following arguments:

- **x,y** = independent Gekko parameters or variables as predictors for z
- **z** = dependent Gekko variable with z = f(x,y)
- **x_data** = 1D list or array of x knots, size (nx)
- **y_data** = 1D list or array of y knots, size (ny)
- **z_data** = 2D list or matrix of c coefficients, size (nx-kx-1)*(ny-ky-1)
- **kx** = degree of spline in x-direction, default=3
- **ky** = degree of spline in y-direction, default=3

Essentially, I want to trick the method into ignoring the **y** independent variable completely.

Comment: What's the reason you don't want to use a 1d cubic spline ([cspline](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html?highlight=spline#cspline))?

Comment: I am not using cubic splines because the model I am using is built on penalized B-splines (*i.e.*, P-splines) and not cubic splines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a zero (or some other nominal) value for `y` in creating the b-spline.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

xgrid = np.linspace(-1, 1, 50)
ygrid = np.linspace(-1e-5,1e-5,50)
xg,yg = np.meshgrid(xgrid,ygrid)

z_data = xg**2

x = m.Var(0.2,lb=-0.8,ub=0.8)
y = m.Param(0)
z = m.Var(0.1)

m.bspline(x,y,z,xgrid,ygrid,z_data)

m.Minimize(z)

m.options.SOLVER=3
m.solve(disp=False)

print(f'x={x.value[0]}')
print(f'y={y.value[0]}')
```

There is also an option to inject the [knots and coefficients directly](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/ObjectBspline) if they are already fit with another function. If this is the case, just keep the value of `y` as a parameter so it is not adjustable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer John. I am sure that I can speak for others when I say that we all appreciate how much time and effort you spend answering gekko-related questions on here. Is it possible to have three or more indepedent variables with m.bspline()? If not, can a B-spline with three or more independent variables be replicated by three or more B-splines of a single independent variable?

Comment: By the way, I am injecting the coefficients and knots directly, which have already been fit with another function.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It is currently up to 2D with Gekko bsplines currently. There may be a creative way to get another dimension but ML methods may be better for higher dimensional models. It is also possible to inject coefficients and knots directly. Another example is provided at: https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/ObjectBspline Make sure that the output data is not dependent on the input `y` when you create the knots and coefficients.

Comment: How difficult would it be to adapt the source code of m.bspline() to accept an arbitrary number of independent variables?

Comment: For a different model, I'm also interested in adapting the source code for m.cspline() to accept more than one independent variable.

Comment: Could you create a feature request on GitHub https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/issues with the proposed addition?

Comment: I will do so. Thank you again for all the help.

Comment: Before I do that, could you please let me know if `m.bspline` and `m.cspline` creates additional variables (such as binary switching variables when using `m.if3` or `m.max3`)?

Comment: The `m.bspline` and `m.cspline` don't create binary variables. Every `m.if3()` function or `m.max3()` function does create a new binary switching variable.